# php add time slot into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following coding and would like to insert a sql into mysql but I got the following error :

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"**

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Hongkong');
include('fun.php');
$outlet="Da Da";
$officehrStr = "11:00"; // morning
$officehrEnd = "02:00"; // midnight
if (isset($_POST['confirm'])) {
    $dt1=new DateTime($officehrStr);
    $dt2=new DateTime($officehrEnd);
    $values=array();
    while ($dt1 <= $dt2) {
        $values[]="('". $outlet ."','". $dt1->format('H:i') ."')";
        $dt1->modify("+".$_POST['slot']." minute");
    }

    include('db.php');
    $sql="INSERT INTO tb_timeslot (outlet,timeslot) VALUES ". implode(',',$values);
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: Try moving your `date_default_timezone_set()` function after you establish your connection to your database. See if it works

Comment: removed but still the same....

Comment: Where did you establish your database connection? Is it in your `fun.php`? And where does your error point to? Error will also state on what file where the problem is, not just the line error. Your error message is incomplete. And shouldn't it be `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Hong_Kong');`?

Comment: I use "db.php" file to establish mysql, the error message I got it after submission of the form button....and the timezone is working fine in my another mysql DBs...

Comment: Could you complete the error message? To know what file does the error persist

Comment: I saw the answer and your response to it. Now my concern is your logic. What do you have in `$values`? Not fixed amount of rows. Am I correct?

Comment: The error is "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1". However, if I change the value of the variable of "$officehrEnd" to "23:45" less than "00:00", The above coding is working fine.

Comment: Can you please create a `var_dump($values);` of a minified version of `$values`(which still generates the error) and then edit your post and add it to your question?

Answer (score 0):

If this is SQL syntax error, my guess is a problem with this line

```
$sql="INSERT INTO tb_timeslot (outlet,timeslot) VALUES ".    implode(',',$values);
```

Try to change it with this

```
$sql="INSERT INTO tb_timeslot (outlet,timeslot) VALUES (".    implode(',',$values).");";
```

Comment: Thanks.  however, if I changed the sql, I got another error..."Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Comment: That means the `$value` variable isn't match with your tables `(outlet,timeslot)`. Are you sure the `$value` value only contain exactly the value for `outlet` and `timeslot`?

Comment: Sorry I dodn't see your `$values[]="('". $outlet ."','". $dt1->format('H:i') ."')";` line. Please change the SQL syntax to this `$sql="INSERT INTO tb_timeslot (outlet,timeslot) VALUES ".    implode(',',$values).";";`

Comment: I still got this error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1".  However, if I change the value of the variable of "$officehrEnd" to "23:45" less than "00:00", The above coding is working fine.

Comment: Then the problem is because the `while` statement. When the condition is not `false` your `$value` dont have real value, just empty array. Which is why you get error on certain time. Better change the `while` to `if else` statement, OR MOVE your SQL script INSIDE the `while` statement

Answer (score 0):

the problem get solved by adding the following coding "$dt2->add(new DateInterval('PT86400S')); " between $dt2=new DateTime($officehrEnd); and while ($dt1 <= $dt2) {" Thank you for all your valuable time

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look in your sql statement.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO tb_timeslot (outlet,timeslot) VALUES (".    implode(',',$values).");";
```

You can see that you are trying to insert data in two columns (outlet,timeslot) but assigning values to inly 1 column. You must assign 2 values like.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO tb_timeslot (outlet,timeslot) VALUES (".    implode(',',$values).", '$replace_variable_name');";
```

Please update your statement with my statement but don't forget to edit "replace_variable_name" with your defined value.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Please read the question carefully. in each row if the array `$values` there is a string with both required values for the query

Comment: the problem get solved by adding the following coding  "$dt2->add(new DateInterval('PT86400S'));
" between $dt2=new DateTime($officehrEnd); and while ($dt1 <= $dt2) {"  Thank you for all your valuable time.